# How do I stop multiple UIButton pressing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

Imagine I have a `UIView` and to that I add 2 `UIButton`s.

I find that I can put a finger on one button, then, holding the first, I can touch the 2nd button with another finger. Both buttons will show their `UIControlStateHighlighted` images.

Is there a way to stop the 2nd touch working? I thought that `multipleTouchEnabled = NO` was the answer, but seems not!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

use a property of UIButton called exclusiveTouch

Comment: I don't think that property was intended for that purpose. I went with this approach instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32267367/2359049

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)button1Pressed {
    button2.enabled = NO;
}
-(IBAction)button2Pressed {
    button1.enabled = NO;
}
```

For touch down.

Then for touch up inside and touch up outside.

```
-(IBAction)button1Lifted {
    button2.enabled = YES;
}
-(IBAction)button1Lifted {
    button2.enabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you tab on 1st button, in Button's IBAction method,make a user interaction of a 2nd button disabled.(On 1st line)
and in last line of 1st button IBAction code, make 2nd button user interaction enabled.(on last line). set IBAction to touchDown.

& vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

add this property to each button\n 
button.exclusiveTouch=YES;